# solution for performing final work when winform is no longer needed

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to accomplish the following.

1.) I have a winform (winformA) that is hidden instead of closed

2.) the winform in #1 is a child to the mainform, when i shutdown the mainform, the child form WinformA is disposed.  I need to save data from a winform control in the winformA

The content is in a ListView in WinformA.  I have tried overriding the dispose and using the destructor ~classname, but the listview items are null at that point.  I cannot do it in form closing because i dont want the action to take place until the whole app is being shutdown.  I cannot expose the method to the mainform due to security requirements.  I have tried subscribing to Application.ApplicationExit but the event does not fire.

Any idea?

Comment: out of curiosity can you explain the security requirement

Comment: The code in WinformA cannot be exposed.  All of the shutdown functionality has to be internal and not callable from another assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot do it in form closing

You have to do it from your FormClosing event handler.  Pay attention to the e.CloseReason value.

Fwiw, the 'security requirements' are a pipe dream with System.Reflection in a programmer's arsenal.  You'll have to setup a sandbox to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you save your items to a variable instead of a UI control?

Then maybe it won't be null when you reference it.